# Gedit Window split into two

Tags: gedit

My gedit window is split into two halves along the length each of which has a different shade. How can I shift it back to the original view.

See image below:

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of what you see. You can upload the screenshot to somewhere like [imgur](https://imgur.com/) and then link to it in your question. To add the link to your question, please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off display right margin in preferences. The checkbox is checked as shown below:

[image: geditprefs]

Comment: I can't seem to find that option. could you include a screenshot uploaded to imgur.com?

Comment: It's the second tick box that you see when you open the preferences window. It should have a number box next to it. I would provide a screenshot but I'm currently on mobile.

Comment: No worries, I edited it in for you.

Comment: Yeah, that's the right margin. Go to Edit > Preferences... and then untick the right margin tick box there.